# Animation not working in Some View controllers

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to animate increase in width of a view. It works fine in first/base view controller. But it does not work in other view controller.
First I loaded 2nd view controller as:

```
let vc = SecondViewController(nibName: "SecondViewController", bundle: nil)
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Then in its viewDidLoad method I used:

```
        UIView.animateWithDuration(10.0, delay:4, options: nil , animations: {

               self.progressBarView.frame = CGRectMake(self.progressBarView.frame.origin.x, self.progressBarView.frame.origin.y, 367, self.progressBarView.frame.size.height)

        }, completion: nil)
```

This animation works fine in first view controller loaded at start but doesn't work in 2nd view controller, but view frame is set without animation. It looks like neither does work delay nor the duration of animation in 2nd view controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is called before the view controller's view is sized to the current display size. If you look at the VC's contentView.frame in viewDidLoad, you'll see that it is the size defined in the XIB/Storyboard, not the correct size.

You should probably put your animation in `viewWillAppear:`

However, viewWillAppear: is called every time the VC's view is displayed, not just the first time, so you need to allow for that.

Another consideration: If you're using AutoLayout, you shouldn't be manipulating view frames. Instead you should set up outlets to constraints on those views, and change the values of those constraints.